# Как наследовать дефолтное значение блока

Tags: css, sass

Здравствуйте, вот есть у меня блок с шириной 327пикс и высотой 486пикс и я при адаптивности ищу данный блок чтобы считать данные значение, в возможно есть какое-то свойство которое позволяет унаследовать дефолтное значение блока во все места где он прописывается? Например как есть унаследование с помощью inherit от родителя, а мне нужно от самого блока одного и того же
Например

```
block
    width: 327px это дефолтное значение
    height: 486px это дефолтное значение

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px)
    .block
        width: сюда хочу получить дефолтное значение
        height: сюда хочу получить дефолтное значение

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px)
    .block
        width: сюда хочу получить дефолтное значение
        height: сюда хочу получить дефолтное значение
```

Comment: добавь пример своей разметки и кода, не совсем понятно, что ты хочешь получить в итоге

Comment: @Grundy Добавил пример, надеюсь что уже более чем понятно

Comment: ничего не присваивай и будет дефолтное значение

Comment: @Grundy да я знаю что будет дефолнтное значение, ты пойми, мне надо проводить рассчеты, и поэтому я всегда должен прописывать дефолнтное значение!

Comment: какая связь с проведением расчетов? Что за расчеты? Если ты не хочешь менять значение у блока - не меняй его, и оно останется таким как и было.

Comment: @Grundy ну какая разница для чего мне? Я спрашиваю как мне его получить, а не для чего это мне пригодится, если я прошу значит надо!!!!

Comment: судя по коду, ты используешь препроцессор, сохрани значение в переменную и используй переменную

Comment: _ну какая разница для чего мне?_ - на самом деле большая. CSS - никак не позволяет искать значения, если ты имел ввиду для расчетов в javascript, то если ты не установишь новое значение, старое вполне нормально получится, если ты имел ввиду вариант со своим препроцессором - используй переменные

Comment: @Grundy это не вариант, так как сам понимаешь в макете может быть сотни блоков и создавать сотню переменных не хочется, да и по времени такое создание займет столько же если не больше как поиск блока с дефолтными значениями

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63994/discussion-between-grundy-and-liem).

Answer (score 0):

Просто указать

```
width: auto;
```

А ещё можно почитать про `initial` и `unset`, но в данном случае это не требуется.

Comment: К сожалению нельзя так написать width: auto*0.8 может можно как-то подругому, чтобы данное свойство я мог на 20% уменьшить?

Comment: @LiEm, `80%`, не?